# Ruby Fiddle dll search Path

Tags: ruby, dll, libffi, fiddle

I am trying to load a dll using the following fiddle code: ( If there is a easier way to load a dll and call a function on it that would solve my problem I am happy to hear it )

```
require 'fiddle' unless defined?(Fiddle)
require 'fiddle/import' unless defined?(Fiddle::Importer)
extend Fiddle::Importer
dlload "Foo.dll"
```

`dlload "C:/Folder/Foo.dll"` works like I want. But the problem is that Foo.dll is a c++ dll that requires several other dlls in various locations.

How do I go about just calling `dlload "Foo.dll"` without a full path. In short how do I add a list of directories to the Ruby dll search path?

I have tried the following:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift("C:/Folder")
ENV['RUBYLIB'] = "C:/Folder"
ENV['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "C:/Folder"
```

The ruby interpreter is running inside another program (Sketchup), so my environment is restricted.

Comment: In my experience I haven't been able to get Fiddle to automagically find my DLL files on any system other than MacOS.

On Linux, I've used pkg-config in the past, but that's not friendly to non-devs who won't have pkg-config. I then used ldconfig directly.

On Windows, I wrote a ruby script that searches for the DLL in the current working directory, then Windows/System32, then the Windows folder itself. That seems to be the search order of most Windows apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I got to work was writing a small kernel32.dll library and calling AddDllDirectory from within it.